# Oracle SQL: Importing datestamp in UTC format

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, utc

I have some data in csv format I'm trying to import into a db. The datetime format in the CSV is as follows:

2013-12-01 08:05:47 (+00:00)

It's always +00:00 as it's relative to GMT and from a GMT source. I'm having some difficulty inserting this format to a timestamp field.

I'm using this syntax at the moment, but I don't think it's correct:
to_timestamp('2014-01-01 08:16:02 (+00:00)', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS GMT')

Can anyone offer some assistance?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2014-01-01 08:16:02 (+00:00)', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS (TZH:TZM)')
```

(not tested)